# Is it possible to share single instance profile between multiple aws ec2 instances?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, share, multiple-instances

Is it possible to share single instance profile between multiple aws ec2 instances?
When I launch instane I can pass instance profile arn/name to it. Can I use single instance profile for different instance launches? Or I need every time create new one with the same roles specified?
I know that I can share a role between profiles, the question is about profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The IAM instance profiles can be reused for many instances. This way, you can startup an entire fleet of EC2 instances using the same IAM profile/role.